# Proof that every quadratic residue has two roots, modulo a prime

Tags: prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic, quadratic-residues

Can someone provide a proof that every quadratic residue, when working in $\mathbb Z_p$, where $p$ is a prime, has exactly two roots? Indeed, there cannot be only one root as for any $a^2$, we know $a$ and $-a$ are both roots. So then we need only show that there cannot be more than two- does this follow from some argument for the number of roots a quadratic can have modulo a prime? I'm not well-acquainted with the theorems pertaining to prime moduli.

Comment: The ring $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ is a field for $p$ prime. Hence any polynomial $f$ has at most $\mathrm{deg}(f)$ roots. In particular any quadratic has at most two roots.

Comment: So in order for the fundamental theorem of algebra to carry over, we need a field? Or... what is the statement there?

Comment: I wouldn't call the fact that a polynomial has at most its degree as number of roots the "fundamental theorem of algebra" but essentially yes. E.g. over $\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$ the polynomial $2x$ has degree $1$ and $2$ roots which can never happen over a field.

Answer (score 2):

Isn't it that the polynomial $X^2-a^2\in \mathbb{K}[X]$ cannot have more than two roots in $\mathbb{K}$. This is the consequence of a reasoning on degrees

Answer (score 1):

This nothing special about quadratic residues.
Use the theorem about roots of polynomial leading to a linear factor: that is, if $a$ is a root of the polynomial $f(x)$ then $(x-a)$ is a factor of $f(x)$. This theorem is also valid for polynomials with coefficients in the field of $p$ elements. So a polynomial of degree $n$ can't have more than $n$ roots.

Answer (score 0):

The definition of an integer $x$ being a quadratic residue (mod p) is equivalent to the statement that there exists an integer $a$ so that $x$=$a$(mod p). But this in itself is equivalent to saying that $x^2$-$a$=$0$(mod p). So now one can conisder working over the field $\mathbb Z$/$p$$\mathbb Z$[$x$]. But by the fundamental theorem of algebra, such a polynomial must have at most $2$ roots in $\mathbb Z$/$p$$\mathbb Z$[$x$].